# Update flutter font with a function

Tags: flutter, dart, text

I want to update the displaying font in flutter using a function.I've tried with following method but it won't update.I can't find the problem.

Function

```
_fontselect(String ){
    if (_character==1) {
      return "Font";
    } else{
      return "Font2";
    }
  }
```

context

```
  Center(child: Text(text,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily:_fontselect(String),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 28.0,
                color: Colors.red)
                   ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Ternary Operator` within the `fontFamily` itself.

```
Center(child: Text(text,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: _character==1 ? "Font" : "Font2",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 28.0,
                color: Colors.red)
               ),
),
```

Comment: Ahhh that's great idea..I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs a String variable to use inside of the function.

```
 _fontselect(String character){
   if (character==1) {
     return "Font";
   } else{
     return "Font2";
   }
}
```

Also it looks like character is an int but you are sending a String over to the function you should call the function with an int if this makes more sense.